# How to early return from within a helper function?

Tags: python, return, helper

So I thought I was being smart and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by removing a bunch of common code from a bunch of similar functions and turning them into helper functions all defined in a single place.  (see [GitHub diff](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/61b18f243fb2abdd0f826928747df1fa77be727a))  That way they can all be modified from a single place.  (see [another GitHub diff](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/b2da9a2b51c9de603611ca30e9f23349512d67a9))

So originally it was

```
func_A(stuff):
    if stuff == guard_condition:
        return early
    things = boilerplate + stuff
    do A-specific stuff(things)
    return late

func_b(stuff):
    if stuff == guard_condition:
        return early
    things = boilerplate + stuff
    do B-specific stuff(things)
    return late
```

and I changed it to

```
_helper(stuff):
    if stuff == guard_condition:
        return early
    things = boilerplate + stuff
    return things

func_A(stuff):
    things = _helper(stuff)
    do A-specific stuff(things)
    return late

func_B(stuff):
    things = _helper(stuff)
    do B-specific stuff(things)
    return late
```

But then I tried it and realized that since I had moved the early returns ("guards"?) into the helper function, they were of course no longer working.  Now I could easily add some code to the original functions to handle those cases, but it seems there's no way to do that without just moving complexity back into the individual functions again and being repetitive.

What's the most elegant way to handle situations like this?

Comment: ohhh, is this what decorators are for?

Comment: [Using python decorators to implement guards](http://www.siddharta.me/2006/12/using-python-decorators-to-implement.html)

Comment: Ah but if the functions to be wrapped take different numbers of arguments ,you need to use `*args` in the decorator, which then becomes the function signature, which is ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
 def common_stuff(f):
    def checked_for_guards(*args, **kwargs):
        if stuff == guard_condition:
            return early
        things = boilerplate
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return checked_for_guards

@common_stuff
def func_A(stuff):
    do A-specific stuff(things)
    return late

@common_stuff
def func_b(stuff):
    do B-specific stuff(things)
    return late
```

Comment: one thing I didn't think of is that func_A and func_B take different numbers of arguments, but that means the wrapper function would need to use `*args`, which will then become the signature of the function being wrapped, which is moderately ugly, so I think I'll have to use the other solution.

Comment: The above code works for any type or arguments for both func_a and func_b. The wrapped function passes all the argument it receives as it is to func_a or func_b.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract `a-specific stuff` and `b-specific stuff` to core functions, that are passed to your helper function. Then the helper will decide whether to call the core functions:

```
_helper(stuff, _core_func):
    if stuff == guard_condition:
        return early
    things = boilerplate
    return _core_func(things)

_a_core(_things):
    do a-specific stuff
    return late

_b_core(_things):
    do b-specific stuff
    return late

func_A(stuff):
    return _helper(stuff, _a_core)

func_B(stuff):
    return _helper(stuff, _b_core)
```

---

EARLIER ANSWER, BEFORE UNDERSTANDING RETURN VALS FROM HELPER

I would give `_helper` a return value:

```
_helper(stuff):
    if guard:
        return False
    boilerplate
    return True

func_a(stuff):
    if _helper():
        do a-specific stuff
    return

func_b(stuff):
    if _helper():
        do b-specific stuff
    return
```

Comment: hmm, it does have a return value.  I guess I should make my example more like the actual code

Comment: You can use the same principle though. Make the return value a tuple where the added element is whether `_helper` went through the early return path or the full path.

Comment: Yes, but that's what I meant by "adding the complexity back to the original functions"

Comment: Hmm, yes that could work.  Still seems like there could be a better way, though.